# Import materials from another blend file: how to deal with name issues?

Tags: materials, append

I want to append a material from another blend file, but I have problems to get the appended materail:

```
#This works fine
with bpy.data.libraries.load(self.blendpath, link=False) as (data_from, data_to):
            data_to.materials = ["myTestMaterial"]
#This is the problem maker
mat = bpy.data.materials.get("myTestMaterial")
```

The problem is that the new material is named "myTestMaterial001" after I run the script for the secound time, is there a way to get the material object directly?

Answer (score 0):

You did, but blender renamed it because the old imported data was still in this file, even if not used. You can get rid of unused data blocks in File -> External Data -> Clean Up -> Purge, then try re-appending the material.